# The file usables.py cannot import name 'FountainOfYouthSprite' from 'resources'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Right after fixing a problem with class objects in my resources file (which keeps all of the sprite and music data suddenly has difficulties with trying to import its data to the usables file, which describes the functions of weapons and items.

Not only that, if I remove FountainofYouthSprite from the import list, it reports that the next item on the list, Selectable_Reticle isn't there either.

Resources file contents:

```
import pygame
from Animation import *
from FECD import char
pygame.init()
Selectable_Reticle = pygame.image.load("Images/Tiles/ITEMS AND SELECTABLES/Selectable Box.png").convert()
Recoverable_Reticle = pygame.image.load("Images/Tiles/ITEMS AND SELECTABLES/Selectable Recovery Box.png").convert()
Smoke_Reticle = pygame.image.load("Images/Tiles/ITEMS AND SELECTABLES/Smoke Box.png").convert_alpha()
Thunder_Reticle = pygame.image.load("Images/Tiles/ITEMS AND SELECTABLES/Thunder Box.png").convert()
FountainOfYouthSprite = pygame.image.load("Images/Tiles/ITEMS AND SELECTABLES/Fountain of youth.png").convert_alpha()
```

Usables file contents:

```
import pygame
import random
from resources import FountainOfYouthSprite, Selectable_Reticle, Recoverable_Reticle, Smoke_Reticle, Thunder_Reticle, CharUnderFog, PotionUseSound, ScrimitarClashSound
from Character import Character
from utils import blit_alpha
```

Main file contents:

```
# all of the importing from different files
from math import sin, cos
from resources import *
from usables import *
from utils import *
from Map import *
from Menu import *
from InputManager import *
from Character import *
```

I expect the game to just work properly work or a message for too many positional arguments for the Animation function but that's a different subject for now.

Comment: Does replacing `from resources import FountainOfYouthSprite, Selectable_Reticle, ...` with `import resources` also cause an error? Are `resources.py` and `usables.py` in the same folder?

Comment: changing anything to just import *something* causes a problem. not to mention that just writing from resources import * also causes issues. All of the code files are in the same folder.